# showing print window after confirm dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a case where I have to first show a confirm dialog box and if user clicks ok, the it will show print window and if user click cancel then it will not show print window.

a href="#" class="btn btn-sm primary float-right hidden-print <%=params[:print_on_load] ? "Mandatory_print_invoice" : ""%>" onClick="window.print();">Print a"

Here print window is showing after click on print. But I have to show first a confirm dialog box after click on print then it will show print window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  if (confirm("Do you want to print?")) {
    window.print();
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Print</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var $dialog_btn = $('#dialog-btn'),
    $print_box = $('#print-box'),
    $print_btn = $('#print-btn');

$dialog_btn.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $print_box.fadeIn();
});
 
 
$print_btn.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.print();
});
```

```css
#print-box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 5px #000;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 50px;
}

#print-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: red;
}

#dialog-btn {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="dialog-btn">Show dialog</a>

<div id="print-box">
  <a href="#" id="print-btn">Print?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
$(document).on('click','button',function()
{
   if(confirm("Print"))
   {
     window.print();
   }
});
```